# Iphone7s Landscape Media Query

Tags: html, css, responsive

I am facing an issue in responsiveness of **iPhone 7s** *portrait* and *landscape* mode. I didn't found any specific media query on the internet so far. I have picked some media queries from [Sitephen Media Queries](http://stephen.io/mediaqueries/). It worked well on Chrome Responsiveness checker. But when I am checking it on iPhone 7s(Mobile). It is not working.

Can someone help me out? Any help will be Appreciated.

Comment: can you post what you have? did you see the page http://stephen.io/mediaqueries/#iPhone with the info for all the iphones?

Comment: I have used iPhone media queries for any resolution. but it wouldn't work on iPhone.but it is limited to chrome responsiveness browser only.

Answer (score 2):

Be specific and this might help you.

```
/* ----------- iPhone 6, 6S, 7, 7S and 8 ----------- */

    /* Portrait and Landscape */
    @media only screen 
      and (min-device-width: 375px) 
      and (max-device-width: 667px) 
      and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) { 

    }

    /* Portrait */
    @media only screen 
      and (min-device-width: 375px) 
      and (max-device-width: 667px) 
      and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
      and (orientation: portrait) { 

    }

    /* Landscape */
    @media only screen 
      and (min-device-width: 375px) 
      and (max-device-width: 667px) 
      and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
      and (orientation: landscape) { 

    }
```

Comment: Thanks. It really helps

Comment: Glad to hear that helps you. Thank you!